# IntelliJ IDEA inspection warning argument might be null

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to tell IDEA that the following is OK:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringValue = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
    long longValue;
    try {
        longValue = Long.parseLong(stringValue);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hmm...", e);
    }
    System.out.println(longValue);
}
```

It insists on highlighting `stringValue` and warning "Argument stringValue might be null". I know it might, but if it is, the exception will be caught.

Comment: The exception is not caught here, because it will be a `NullPointerException`, not a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: You could always do `assert stringValue != null` or annotate it `@NotNull` if it is a parameter to your method

Comment: @RealSkeptic no, `parseLong` checks for null and throws `NumberFormatException`, not `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @user I can't do that because stringValue _can_ be null.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou For me your code does not highlight a warning. Is it vanilla IntelliJ, or is it a plugin?

Comment: @Magnilex it is vanilla IntelliJ (latest version) with possibly some warnings turned up a bit higher than standard. In my case, Settings -> Inspections -> Java -> Probable Bugs -> "Constant Conditions & Exceptions" is turned on at Warning level. I've also edited my question and added a full main method that use can use as a "Complete Minimal Verifiable Example".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, is it really OK? You are essentially using the exception to control the flow of the code. This is generally considered an anti-pattern ([Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)).

It can easily be avoided by doing the null check yourself:

```
if (stringValue != null) {
  longValue = Long.parseLong(stringValue);
}
```

However, if you want to keep your code the way it is and let the `null` case be handled by the `parseLong()` method, you can:

**Annotate your method with `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`**

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String stringValue = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
  long longValue;
  try {
    longValue = Long.parseLong(stringValue);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("hmm...", e);
  }
}
```

**Add a comment `//noinspection ConstantConditions`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String stringValue = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
  long longValue;
  try {
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    longValue = Long.parseLong(stringValue);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("hmm...", e);
  }
}
```

---

IntelliJ helped me with both these by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, bringing up the intentions menu where you can either choose *Supress for method* or *Supress for statement*.

However, I think both of these are IDE-specific, so my advise would simply be to let the warning be. Or even better, do the null check yourself.